# 1982 chevrolet p-30 southwind 31 foot motorhome replace airlift airbags inside the coil springs on front

Tags: suspension

how can I install airlift air bags in a 1982 Chevrolet p30 chassis , since air lift lied about installation of airbag through the small 2 inch circle on lower A arm, it looks like the removal of big sway bar which attaches to the lower a arms then the shock absorber,s, also the tie rod link,s, and i,m confused about the lower a arm disassembly the lower ball joint to release lower a arm and get the coil spring out and put the airlift bag back inside the coil spring and bolt everything back up in some certain order of re-assembly

this is a dangerous job , I,m disabled with most tools, might need a pickle bar for the tie rods, and hopefully don't need a spring compressor.i haven't been able to secure help, living miles from any real qualified mechanics,in a very remote area, cant even get mobile phone service in the area.   please consider helping ME GET THIS STRAIGHT , I,m a first responder with federal-state whistleblower, terrible vendetta victims death and disabilities , they sabotaged
just about the whole rv , and every physics projects i was heir too, southern cal,really unbelievable damages to the rv, after trump made the presidency, the official leakers syndrome, 
the rv  front end is jacked up with 2 jack stands and wooden blocks , and heavy 
concrete blocks as a back up, have a floor jac and 10 ton,12 ton bottle jacks 
in support as well, the wheels are off, and I can access the complete front end

to send a picture , I would have to learn what to do , but this is a typical
southwind or bounder from the 1980,s , mines an 1982 with 454 and it runs very well when on the road , the local cities in sanctuary programs chased every rv out of san diego areas, they have panicked many older people in retirement , very rude, and had sabotaged transmission, trashed the water tank, 2 fuel pumps, failure really messy, January, 2 air beds ,total failure ,unbelievable battle with the locals in sanctuary migrations

front is lifted and stable after dropping a 10 ton hydraulic bottle jac once ,
it was a badly balanced set of jacks and the front collapsed onto the frame jacks , rebuilt the jack supports with 2 backup units

so i,m ready to drop sway bar , and shocks link,
understand if I use a pickle bar on tie rod link I,ll have to replace the bushings is that difficult?? the big deal is the spindle to lower a arm can I just release the spindle lower ball joint  and drop the lower a arm 
to get the coil spring out and load the airlift bag, thanks for any help really, thanks people

Comment: "this is a dangerous job , I'm disabled with tools and no help" yes it is in your condition.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you please share an image of where exactly you're at in the process? It sounds like you're ready to remove the spring, but I'd like to make sure so someone can give you the best advice possible.